# detecting whether user has rated the app on the appstore or not

Tags: ios, swift

Is there an existing method to check whether the app has been rated or not? At the moment I have a uilabel that sends the user to the SKStoreReviewController to rate the app if they click it. Since apple only allows one rating per user, the label becomes disabled after the user rates, so I want to change the message, change text color, etc.

[image]

```
@IBAction func appRating(_ sender: Any) {
    if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    } else {
        if let url = URL(string: REVIEW_URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method to do so, or no way to understand if a user really rated your app on Appstore. What you can do is:

- Once a user clicks on that "Rate us on the App Store". Set a value like `hasRated` in `Userdefaults` to true, then next time check it if it has a true value, if so, update your label assuming the user has rated your app.

But again, you can never be sure, since they might kill the appstore before rating your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So this might not be possible, but could I generate a uiview/invisible label with the exact dimensions over the "rate" button in the uialert that pops up and detect that? The main problem with the hasRated method is that they could click cancel and it would register as rated

Comment: What if you add an action handler to your alert, and once they have an action, write the value to userdefaults in that handler? But I'm not sure about generating an invisible view or label inside alertView, because it is advised against to insert and modify view hierarchy of alerts as stated in documentation:

Important

The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: interesting...what a massive headache. I guess it's to prevent app makers from differentiating between those who rate and those who don't. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am also wondering how to do this. I encountered an app (https://waterllama.com) that unlocks functionality once the user has left a review